# Query String Serializer

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, parsing, reflection

I have a ASP.NET Web Forms project, and I want to build calls to .aspx pages in a strongly-typed fashion. I ended up rolling my own serializer that takes simple structs and saves them to/loads them from the query string. What do you think? Is my approach sane? Is there an accepted alternative I don't know about? Any feedback on the code?

Here's what building a call to a particular page looks like:

```
var fooParams= new FooPage.Parameters
{
    NodeID = nodeId,
    FooString = "the foo string"
};
string url = MyHelper.BuildCall(FooPage.URL, fooParams);
//url: ~/dir/FooPage.aspx?NodeID=5&FooString=the%20foo%20string
```

FooPage:

```
public partial class FooPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public const string URL = "~/Dir/FooPage.aspx";
    public struct Parameters
    {
        public long? NodeID;
        public string FooString;
        public int? OtherParam;
    }

    protected Parameters Params;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Params = MyHelper.DeserializeFromNameValueCollection<Parameters>(Request.Params);

        //...
        //use Params.NodeID, Params.FooString, etc..
    }
}
```

Serialize/Deserialize to/from NameValueCollection:

```
public static void SerializeToNameValueCollection<T>(NameValueCollection nameValueCollection, T @object) where T : struct
{
    Type type = typeof(T);

    var fields = type.GetFields();
    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        string key = field.Name;
        var value = field.GetValue(@object);

        if (value != null)
            nameValueCollection.Add(key, value.ToString());
    }
}

public static T DeserializeFromNameValueCollection<T>(NameValueCollection nameValueCollection) where T : struct
{
    T result = new T();

    Type type = typeof(T);

    var fields = type.GetFields();

    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        string key = field.Name;

        string stringValue = nameValueCollection[key];
        if (stringValue != null)
        {
            object value;

            var baseType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(field.FieldType);
            if (baseType != null)
            {
                value = Convert.ChangeType(stringValue, baseType);
            }
            else
            {
                value = Convert.ChangeType(stringValue, field.FieldType);
            }

            field.SetValueDirect(__makeref(result), value);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Format NameValueCollection into query string:

```
public static string BuildCall<T>(string url, T queryStringParams) where T : struct
{
    var queryStringBuilder = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("");

    UrlHelper.SerializeToNameValueCollection(queryStringBuilder, queryStringParams);

    string queryString = queryStringBuilder.ToString();

    return url + "?" + queryString;
}
```

Comment: The line that parses an empty string seems a bit of a hack to get a NamveValueCollection. `var queryStringBuilder = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("");` Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my favorite patterns for handling URL parameters in WebForms is the WebNavigator - http://polymorphicpodcast.com/shows/webnavigator/

If you're going through these kinds of Strongly-typed interactions for passing parameters between pages, maybe it is time you check out ASP .NET MVC - your solution looks a lot like model-binding.

Comment: This is great, I didn't know about the WebNavigator pattern! I would LOVE to use MVC (and MVC did inspire this approach), but unfortunately the product I'm working on can't afford the time it'd take to do the switch.